# C++ YOLOv5: Failed to parse onnx model in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20190621::ONNXImporter::ONNXImporter'

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning, yolov5

I want to use YOLOv5 for object detection Using C++ and OpenCV's DNN.
I'm using Windows 10, and VS 2019.

However, the following line of code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int, char **)
{
    auto net = cv::dnn::readNet("yolov5s.onnx");
    
    return 0;
}
```

causes the following error:

```
 OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\opencv-4.1.1\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:57: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) Failed to parse onnx model in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20190621::ONNXImporter::ONNXImporter'

Press any key to continue . . .
```

**EDIT:**

Seems there was a problem with the path.

After I wrote the full path to the full .onnx file path, as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int, char **)
{
    auto net = cv::dnn::readNet("C:/Users/hedey/source/repos/Road_Defects_Detector/yolov5s.onnx");

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I'm getting the following error:

```
OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\opencv-4.1.1\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:320: error: (-204:Requested object was not found) Blob  not found in const blobs in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20190621::ONNXImporter::getBlob'

Press any key to continue . . .
```